# Possibility of mixed PCB that flex part covers rigid part after coming out of board cutout

Tags: pcb, altium, flexible

I want to design a board with mixed rigid-flex approach, the flex part is carrying some traces from different rigid layers, comes out as a mid layer from a cutout of rigid board but it should covers the top layer of rigid part as its size is extended after cutout. The below picture shows what I mean:

[image: picture trying to explain the problem]

Is it possible to design such a thing using Altium designer and then do manufacturers do this?

Edit: I made a model by color note papers, hope it helps.

[image: front view]
[image: back view]
[image: side view]

Comment: Please edit the post to embed the image into it using the picture link.  Some people can not access bulk image storage sites.

Comment: @hadi the diagram is nice but hard to read, can you draw one up in paint or use a software that can draw diagrams (word or PowerPoint etc)

Comment: I was on mobile, I will edit the picture ASAP. thanks for reply.

Comment: I've never heard of being able to combine flex & rigid PCBs in this way, where the flex is more-or-less laminated in between layers of rigid. But having stiffeners added to flex PCBs is not unusual - perhaps looking at this as if the entire assembly is a flex PCB with large stiffener areas would make sense ... ?

Comment: I'm sorry but that drawing is pretty rough on the eyes, and I can't really figure out what you're asking. Questions about what can be made should be given to the PCB manufacturer, who will also tell you how they want you to represent it.

Comment: @brhans this is rather standard for rigid-flex. E.g. check the last three examples here: https://www.multi-circuit-boards.eu/en/pcb-design-aid/layer-buildup/rigid-flex-pcb.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the flex part to be larger than the cutout and overlapping the rigid part on the left and right? This won't be any kind of standard technology. During manufacturing each intermediate layer stack must be completely flat so that the material can be pressed, cut and drilled.

With some special tooling that might be possible, but I bet you won't like the price tag. Without the overlap you're in the realm of standard technology.

My suggestion would be to have the flexible part longer and then fold it back: (The blue parts are the rigid PCB, the flexible part is in red)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it was exactly what I meant. I' will consider your suggestion.